# SQL distinct values between different queries

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the following query

```
select distinct 
people.id
from people
inner join incident on people.id = incident.peopleid 
where  incident.service =4
AND people.id NOT IN (
select  incident.peopleid
from Incident
where 
incident.service IN =4
AND incident.ServiceInterrupt != 0
)
```

that gives me all the people that belong to a service and they havent interrupt that service yet.
I want to run this query for service 5 and 6 and for these results take only the unique people.
 Till now, i run the query 3 times (changing the service each time) and then i remove the duplicates with excel!!! 
Is there an other way to do it?

thanks in advance

EDIT: To be more specific i want from the results to exclude all people in service X that have interrupt service X only. That is why i cant use incident.service in (4,5,6) instead on incident.service=4

Comment: Whats the purpose of your inner select? Can you not exclude the entire thing and just have the `AND incident.ServiceInterrupt != 0`?

Comment: i need it for other details i have removed for what you see. That is the main thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use something like this;

```
select distinct 
people.id
from people
inner join incident i1 on people.id = i1.peopleid 
where  i1.service in(4,5,6)
AND people.id NOT IN (
select  i2.peopleid
from Incident i2
where 
i2.service = i1.service
AND i2.ServiceInterrupt != 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct 
people.id
from people
inner join incident on people.id = incident.peopleid 
where  incident.service IN(4,5,6)
AND incident.ServiceInterrupt != 0
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but with that not give me the people in service 4 that have interrupt service 5 or 6. I dont want to take only people in service X that have interrupt service X only.